# Stream MongoDB results to Express response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to do this without and 3rd party dependencies, as I don't feel they should be needed. Please note, due to architect ruling we have to use MongoDB native, and not Mongoose (don't ask!).

Basically I have a `getAll` function, that will return all documents (based on passed in query) from a single collection.

The number of documents, could easily hit multiple thousand, and thus, I want to stream them out as I receive them.

I have the following code:

```
db.collection('documents')
    .find(query)
    .stream({
        transform: (result) => {
            return JSON.stringify(new Document(result));
        }
    })
    .pipe(res);
```

Which kind of works, except it destroys the array that the documents should sit in, and it responds `{...}{...}`

There has to be a way of doing this right?

Comment: What's happening after you send the response? Wrapping documents into `[]` will require the client to wait the stream to exhaust to get a JSON-parsable string of "multiple thousand" documents. Wouldn't it make more sense for the client to accept the stream of individually-parsable documents and push them to array if required?

Comment: you are right, and fundamentally, it will be a websocket ultimately. At present though it goes through a seperate service layer that is just a pass through so we want to speed through

Comment: the collecting of all data will currently happen in the client and not before

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to write explicitly the start of the array `res.write("[")` before requesting the database, put a `,`, on every json stringified object and on the stream end write the end of the array `res.write("]")` this can work. **But it is not advisable!**

> `JSON.stringify` is a very slow operation, you should try to use it as less as possible.

A better approach will be to go with a streamable JSON.stringify implementation like [`json-stream-stringify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stream-stringify)

```
const JsonStreamStringify = require('json-stream-stringify');
app.get('/api/users', (req, res, next) => {
   const stream = db.collection('documents').find().stream();
   new JsonStreamStringify(stream).pipe(res);
);
```

> Be aware of using pipe in production, **pipe** does not destroy the source or destination stream when errors. It is advisable to go for [`pump`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pump) or [`pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) in production to avoid memory leaks.